# how to set mute option in android music player with source code

Tags: android, mute

How do I set the Mute option in the Android music player from source code? Please help me.
This is my code. Please check it and give me your ideas.

```
    mute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(mute.isPressed())

                //audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

                mp.setVolume(0,0);

        else if(mute.isPressed())
                mp.setVolume(0, 1);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Don't you need braces in the if statement and else if statement i.e. if(mute.isPressed()) { mp.setVolume(0,0);} ...?

Comment: look at Daniel's comment, moreover your are checking for the same condition in both if and else if.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573667/how-to-mute-mediaplayer-in-android

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!mute.isPressed()) you forgot ! in else if .............


in both if it is mute.isPressed() ...........


and would be better 

    if(mute.isPressed()){
       mp.setVolume(0,0);
    }
    else{ 
      mp.setVolume(0, 1);
    }
```

because mute.isPressed() is a boolean if it is not true so no need to check it has to be false.........

can use code [ImageView Button Toggle in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438014/imageview-button-toggle-in-android)

for you :

```
    final ImageView button01 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button01);

    button01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        boolean isPressed = false;
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isPressed ) {
                //button01.setImageResource(R.drawable.image01);.
                 mp.setVolume(0,0);
            } else {
               //button01.setImageResource(R.drawable.image02);.
                 mp.setVolume(0,1);
            }
            isPressed = !isPressed ;
        }
    });
```

..........................................................................................

```
alternative answer :
```

let us make it intersting :)

```
button01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        int state = 0;
         public void onClick(View v) {
             state = (state+1)%2;
             mp.setVolume(0,state);
        }
    });
```

looks good ?

Comment: mute is image button it press means volume is mute, how can i release again the button? its again i am clicked not release please help.

Comment: there are various logic to main that . like 1- toggleing the tag every time mute.setTag("true")/mute.setTag("false") on onClick 2- keep a bolean and toggle in onClick 3- get which image is currently showing of mute or of unmute.........

Comment: use custom toggle button http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533038/android-specify-two-different-images-for-togglebutton-using-xml

Comment: same problem when i am click mute is working again how can i release it. again i am pressing means sound is not enable. i declare any variable? like true and false.

Comment: yes because in your code it will never go in  else if(mute.isPressed()),  as first/main if is same as if(mute.isPressed()) so either it will go in first if or will not go in any .........

Comment: please give complete code for this. i am using same image button for both.

Comment: is this not works ... :( .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438014/imageview-button-toggle-in-android

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to try

```
mute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(mute.isPressed()){
            mp.setVolume(0,0);
        }
        else if(!mute.isPressed()){
            mp.setVolume(0, 1);
        }
    }});
```

The problems were that you didn't have proper bracketing and that you weren't checking the proper expression in your else if statement. Let us know how that works for you.

Comment: same problem when i am click mute is working again how can i release it. again i am pressing means sound is not enable. i declare any variable? like true and false.

Comment: So, the problem is that you press mute once and the volume mutes as expected, but then you press mute again and the volume remains muted? Try using `setOnItemClickListener` instead of `setOnClickListener`. Not sure if that will fix your problem, but it's worth a try.